# How can I use Twitter Bootstrap to Customize a Rails 3 file_field input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter's Bootstrap css framework and want to make the File Upload fields look better.  With Paperclip I can do something as simple as:

```
<%= asset_fields.file_field :asset %>
```

And this renders:

```
<input id="recommendation_assets_attributes_3_asset" name="recommendation[assets_attributes][3][asset]" type="file" >
```

I can add classes just not sure what makes the most sense in Bootstraps case.

thanks

Comment: you can add class by: `<%= asset_fields.file_field :asset, class: 'bootstrap-class' %>`

Comment: I know I can do that.  I was hoping someone had styled this element before and knew how to make it look good.  Each browser presents it a little differently so I was hoping to create uniformity with Bootstrap

Comment: I just looked around some webs and found info that it's a custom control, so bootstrap have not added style for it to the core. But, fortunately, some one did it :). Take a look a this [jasny bootstrap](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) and [jquery for upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) with styled bootstrap also

Comment: Kien, post your comment as the answer and I'll approve it.  Jasny's stuff worked great.

Comment: I done it. Thanks for accept :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked around some webs and found info that it's a custom control, so bootstrap have not added style for it to the core. But, fortunately, some one did it :). Take a look a this [jasny bootstrap](http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) and [jquery for upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) with styled bootstrap also.